# SDE conditional expectations

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(\Omega,F,F_t,W_t,P)$ a standard Brownian motion. Suppose that I have the following sde with stochastic coefficients:
$$dX_t=b(X_t,Y)dt+\sigma(X_t,Y)dW_t$$
with $X_0=x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y: \Omega \to R$ random variable $F_0$ measurable. Suppose that there is a unique strong solution.

If I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_t|Y]$. is it correct to fix $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_t|Y=y]=\mathbb{E}^y[\tilde{X}_t]$ where $\tilde{X}$ solves

$$d\tilde{X}_t=b(\tilde{X}_t,y)dt+\sigma(\tilde{X}_t,y)dW_t$$

so that I get a function $g(y)$ and then $g(Y)=\mathbb{E}[X_t|Y]$.

Then I ask: by Doob's measurability theorem there exists $f$ such that $f(Y)=\mathbb{E}[X_t|Y]$. But who garantees that $f=g$ obtained by fixing $y$ int the equation for $\tilde{X}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that if $\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\mid Y=y\right]=g(y)$, for all $y$, then $\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\mid Y\right]=g(Y)$.

By definition,
$$
X_t=\int_0^t b(X_s,Y)ds +\int_0^t \sigma(X_s,Y)dW_s
$$
Denote by $\tilde{X}_t^y$ the solution to the SDE for a fixed $y$ (I included  the dependency on y in the notation), then
$$
\tilde{X}_t^y=\int_0^t b(\tilde{X}_s^y,y)ds +\int_0^t \sigma(\tilde{X}_s^y,y)dW_s
$$

Thus, assuming $Y$ is independent on the Wiener process,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
X_t \mid Y=y
\right]
=
\mathbb{E}\left[
\int_0^t b(X_s,Y)ds +\int_0^t \sigma(X_s,Y)dW_s
\mid Y=y
\right]
=\mathbb{E}\left[\tilde{X}_t^Y\mid Y=y
\right]
$$

Comment: yes ok and this is true by freeing lemma since $Y$ is $F_0$ measurable and so it is independent of $dW_t$ for $t \geq 0$ right? So we need the independence is crucial right?

Comment: yes, you are right, we need to assume independence to use freezing lemma. I've edited the answer